# Why don't the buttons get displayed for jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to enable export buttons for a jQuery data table but the buttons don't get displayed.

```
$('#tblServicesReport').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
});
```

Datatables version is 1.10.15

Comment: Have you included the extra required files for the export logic to work? See the docs: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html Specifically the JS and CSS tabs

Comment: I tried this but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Try this, ensure to load all necessary min files.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'surname' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'office' },
            { data: 'salary' }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/4tuupc5f/6/

Ensure to load all required files

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

CSS files

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code or just make a fiddle, so it will help us, have you load all required library files for it?

Comment: If you have a teamviewer I can let you access my system

Comment: Sorry right now I'm in the office I can't make it, why don't you try through any online tool like JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or CodePen etc

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you integrate the buttons javascript library https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js